# Add character every 2 characters entered to textbox Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Hi i want to make textbox to enter mac adress and every 2 characters i want to automaticly add ':'

I wanted to use TextChanged event

```
    private void MacAdressTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (MacAdressTextBox.Text.Length > 2)
            MacAdressTextBox.Text += ":";
    }
```

here i am adding : after 2 characterrs entered but after those 2 characters the app frezes ... have no idea why any help?

Comment: Firstly, specify what is happening after app freezes. Secondly, you should check the length as multiple of 2 otherwise this will enter ":" after every character once length passes 2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the text changes `MacAdressTextBox_TextChanged` is triggered.
2. In `MacAdressTextBox_TextChanged` you change the text.
3. see step 1

your text change causes an infinite recursion on `MacAdressTextBox_TextChanged`.

Comment: but how can i avoid going back to the beginning of string after adding character via code ?

Comment: I guess one option (though not particularly nice), would be to handle the `KeyDown` event instead, check it's an alphanumeric key, and then do the check that @thumbmunkeys mentions to add the character

Comment: @user3311826 while my solution will solve your initial problem, you will run into other issues, eg. when the user deletes characters

Comment: This won't work. User enters "AA", system adds ":". Then user enters one more, "B", now contains "AA:B", which is divisible by 2: system adds another ":". Textbox now contains "AA:B:". Use some kind of masked textbox, don't reinvent the wheel poorly.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to grab the Text, remove the colons, then add them back in at the correct positions. In order to keep the app from hanging in an endless recursive loop, you can add a variable to track whether or not the text is being changed by our code or the user.

For example:

```
// When this is true it means our code is changing the text
private bool updatingTextWithCode = false;

private void MacAdressTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (updatingTextWithCode)
    {
        // Our code is doing the update, so just reset the variable
        updatingTextWithCode = false;
    }
    else
    {
        // The user is updating the text, so process the contents
        var newText = "";

        // Store the mac address without the ':' characters
        var plainText = MacAdressTextBox.Text.Replace(":", "");

        // Then add ':' characters in correct positions to 'newText'
        for (int i = 1; i <= plainText.Length; i++)
        {
            newText += plainText[i - 1];
            if (i % 2 == 0) newText += ":";
        }

        // Set our global variable and update the text
        updatingTextWithCode = true;
        MacAdressTextBox.Text = newText;
        MacAdressTextBox.Select(MacAdressTextBox.TextLength, 0);
    }            
}
```

**UPDATE**: CodeCaster correctly pointed out that this code does not allow the user to backspace over a colon. One way to fix this is to add the following event handler as well:

```
private void MacAdressTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Disable formatting code when backspacing
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back) { updatingTextWithCode = true; }
}
```

Comment: What happens when the user presses backspace when the textbox contains `AA:`? Please use existing controls that solved these problems.

Comment: I guess Windows Phone does not have MaskedTextBox control so it will require to write own implementation

Comment: @CodeCaster You're right. Not sure why it wasn't repro-ing for me before, but I copied/pasted the code and could not backspace over a colon. Added a fix to sample above. Thank you!